# device orientation change in uiviewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift

I want to catch the event in a UIViewcontroller when the device orientations changes and change the view content accordingly. However, the funcs doing this seems to be deprecated. How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

In AppDelegate.swift inside the "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" function put:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "rotated", name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
```

and then inside the AppDelegate class put the following function:

```
func rotated()
{
    if(UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation))
    {            
        println("landscape")
    }

    if(UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation))
    {
        println("Portrait")
    }

}
```

Comment: I want to catch the orientation change in the viewcontroller. I don't understand how to catch this event with the example above.

Comment: If you don't have your AppDelegate set up, you can put the `NotificationCenter...` line in your View Controller's viewDidLoad and add the `func rotated()` as an additional function for your View Controller